# Error Reading JSON from namespace which contains alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

i have a JSON js obejct in

res.metrics.load.1-min
the problem is that this is coming from the server.
i cannot extract anything as it gives illegal number
since res.metrics.load.1-min contains 1-min
Any suggestion i can i parse my JSON. my JSON is an Array

```
"metrics" : {
    "load" : {
      "1-min" : [
        [
          5.87,
          1437031875
        ],
        [
          5.87,
          1437031890
        ]
     ]}}
```

Please help i am using

```
res.metrics.load.1-min = res.metrics.load.1-min.map(
                            function (map) 
                            {
                              return { x: map[1], y: map[0] };
                            });
```

to map values to x and y. its throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update

```
res.metrics.load.1-min
```

to

```
res.metrics.load["1-min"]
```